# Expressjs bodyParser and connect-form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im uploading images with **connect form**. But it does not work if I use the `bodyParser()`.
And the other way around, if i don't use the bodyParser, i cant upload files?

How do I make them play together? Here is my config:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views');
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(gzippo.staticGzip(__dirname + '/../public'),{ maxAge: 86400000 });
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(form({ 
        keepExtensions: true,
        uploadDir: __dirname + '/../tmp'
    }));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'test',
        cookie: { secure: true },
        store: new MySQLSessionStore(client.database, client.user, client.password)
    }));
    app.use(expressValidator);
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.csrf());
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the latest Express you don't need to include connect-form (which is deprecated since Connect 1.8.x).

Just use req.files in your routes to get the uploaded files, Express does the rest. Check out this post:

http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/12943975936/connect-1-8-0-multipart-support

Comment: Oh thats nice :) But now i have a problem with the file name. With `req.files.image.filename` i get the name of the image before it was uploaded. And it´s renamed to a random string or something after. Where is that set? Can't seem to find anything on the subject?

Comment: You get the name and the path for the image. Just move that image from the temporary location into the desired one and you're good to go :)

Comment: The link is broken now, would be better to put the answer in here rather than pasting a link in

Comment: The link is now http://tjholowaychuk.tumblr.com/post/12943975936/connect-180-multipart-support but I think that whole approach is now out of date, search node.js express multipart. I ended up using multer