# Error: Cannot find module 'connect-form' - despite it existing

Tags: node.js

I've got a railwayjs app

I have installed connect-form with:

```
$ npm install connect-form
```

It's also in the package.json file
(for deploying to heroku)

I've checked the node_modules folder, and it's definately there.

When I run the app, I get:

> Error: Cannot find module 'connect-form'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`connect-form` is deprecated (that's probably why it doesn't work), read more about this here:

[Expressjs bodyParser and connect-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481349/expressjs-bodyparser-and-connect-form)