# Have issue with response of submit in ExtJS (response in JSON but somewhere HTML entered)

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

I get this response:

```
{"success":true,"errorCode":-1,"error":""}
```

No HTML inside the JSON, but the js say its entered:

```
uncaught exception: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <pre>{"success":true,"errorCode":-1,"error":""}</pre>
```

The code:
http://www.pasteall.org/30057/javascript

The issue has been fixed that so odd seem like when you upload a file the ExtJS submit can't handle the json response. If you make at html and convert violà you got at.

```
$this -> output -> set_content_type('text/html');
```

that all the problem

Comment: guys give u snap to the  how its look in the debuger so u see not server problem http://www.pasteall.org/pic/28472

Comment: Oh please, at least attempt to write proper English. "u" is not a proper substitute for "you".

Comment: sorry for my english just my writing skills are bad for dyslexia i have please forgive me:)

Comment: No problem, it's not your fault that there are so many people who are really just so plain careless in their writing that it tends to piss me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to analyze the problem without seeing the code, so if you can add your code piece of client side, it may help.

Anyway, it seems that the result is returned in html format, i.e. contains non json data. Check why  tags are included inside the result.

Check also the configuration of your server's page - it should be configured properly so to return JSON format.

It also explains why your result status is success. it is because the call to server operation was succeeded, i.e. the result was return to client without any error.

Now, after the server returned results to client, the store tries to operate the resulted data, but without success since the content is not in JSON format.

Comment: These days I investigate the similar problem, so I will inform you about any progress.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you experienced is actually documented (quite well buried, though) in ExtJS API docs - see description of [Ext.form.Basic.hasUpload()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload) method.

In short, file uploads are not performed by typical Ajax `XMLHttpRequests`. It uses a hidden `iframe` element instead. As a result, to quote ExtJS documentation:

> If the server is using JSON to send the return object, then the
>   Content-Type header must be set to "text/html"...

Which is exactly how you seemed to eventually solve your problem - so, this explains why it indeed works. So it's "not a bug, but a feature". :-D

Comment: +1, In IE11, returning app/json as response to file import, prompts you to save the JSON as a file. Setting to text/html makes Ext act's correctly. Both FF/Chrome don't care if it's app/json or text/html, they behave correct both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Command `Ext.JSON.decode('{"success":true,"errorCode":-1,"error":""}');` should parse the JSON response just fine.

Are you sure the error is not exactly what it says - does your response include the `<pre>...</pre>` tags by accident?

Comment: very i can give screen shot to the debug its somewhere give <pre> when the response type json (not the server give 100%)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I insert a file field. If you delete it, it works. The problem does not come from the response itself. You have to manage the upload file on the server side.

Between server and client, response is transformed from 'json' to an html response.

see [Uploading images using Node.js, Express, and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149545/uploading-images-using-nodejs-express-and-mongo)