# how to handle multipart/form-data in node.js

Tags: forms, node.js, multipartform-data

I am uploading image file from client side using multipart form data. I want to receieve and write it as a file in the server side using node.js.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="imageName">
            <input type="file" name="sam">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my client side code. How to handle this file in server side.

Answer (score 2):

It is repeated question below link.

[Uploading images using Node.js, Express, and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149545/uploading-images-using-nodejs-express-and-mongo)

Here is example:

```js
// Expose modules in ./support for demo purposes
require.paths.unshift(__dirname + '/../../support');

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('../../lib/express')
  , form = require('connect-form');

var app = express.createServer(
  // connect-form (http://github.com/visionmedia/connect-form)
  // middleware uses the formidable middleware to parse urlencoded
  // and multipart form data
  form({ keepExtensions: true })
);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
    + '<p>Image: <input type="file" name="image" /></p>'
    + '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>'
    + '</form>');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next){

  // connect-form adds the req.form object
  // we can (optionally) define onComplete, passing
  // the exception (if any) fields parsed, and files parsed
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files){
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('\nuploaded %s to %s'
        ,  files.image.filename
        , files.image.path);
      res.redirect('back');
    }
  });

  // We can add listeners for several form
  // events such as "progress"
  req.form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected){
    var percent = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100) | 0;
    process.stdout.write('Uploading: %' + percent + '\r');
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express app started on port 3000');
```

If your question is not solve then please visit  [this link](http://www.componentix.com/blog/9/file-uploads-using-nodejs-now-for-real)  . This is a nice article  about file uploading.

Answer (score -7):

You can use request module for sending a multipart request. Here is the sample code:

```
var jsonUpload = {  };
var formData = {
    'file': fs.createReadStream(fileName),
    'jsonUpload': JSON.stringify(jsonUpload)
};
var uploadOptions = {
    "url": "https://upload/url",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    "formData": formData
}
var req = request(uploadOptions, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('upload successful', body)
    }
});
```

Comment: He want to *Handle* the data, not send it.