# Best practice for writing UIImage data to server

Tags: objective-c, node.js, uiimage, base64, nsdata

I was thinking along the lines of sending base64 encoded NSData of the UIImage but the image is corrupted. I'm using https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64 for Base64 encoding.

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myViewImage,1.0);

NSString *stringSentToServer = [data base64EncodedString];

// POST data to nodeJS
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("mydirectory/image.png", "data:image/png;base64,"+(POSTED stringSentToServer here), function(err) {    
if(err) console.log(err); else console.log('Success');
});
```

The filesize saved looks appropriate, but the image is corrupt. What am i doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

** EDIT **
I've tried AFNetworking multipart upload. I'm receiving positive progress callback, but the image is still corrupt on the server.

Comment: What you posted does not show how you used the Base64 class.
Can you provide us with more details ?

Comment: How do you upload your data to the server? Are you using multipart upload or do you just put stringSentToServer into the body of your POST?

Comment: I just post the string to body

Comment: I would personally recommend using Multipart upload instead of putting a string directly into the body. A good library to use would be AFNetworking.

Comment: @Arcanfel I have not tried AFNetworking Multipart upload. I get positive progress callback but the image is still saving corrupted.

Comment: Is the length of the string the same before and after upload?

Comment: @Arcanfel I'm using the File Upload With Progress from the doc https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking, it doesnt specify a post string.

Comment: It is because it takes image data and uploads it using multipart upload method. You need to make sure your server accepts this type of request.

Comment: @Arcanfel How can i accept AFNetowork multipart upload with NodeJS ?

Comment: I am not an expert in node.js, but I think this discussion should help you a lot - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149545/uploading-images-using-nodejs-express-and-mongo

Comment: i know its too late but you can try this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267939/nodejs-write-base64-image-file