# How to get other type fields when Multipart/form-data in expresses

Tags: node.js, forms, express, upload

I'm creating a form to upload an image and at the same time this form contains other fields. The problem is that when I try to get the form data with `req.body` there an undefined. do you know why? it is not possible to get other input when using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Please, check if you not forget to use https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: I'm already using it

Comment: It's strange that body is undefined if you use body-parser in right way. Look here for solutions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149545/uploading-images-using-node-js-express-and-mongoose

Comment: Did you have any success using `multiparty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) module as follows

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');

exports.parseForm = function (req, res) {

   var form = new multiparty.Form();
   form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

     //here you can read the appropriate fields/files

   });
};
```

Also be sure you are setting the `enctype` correctly in your html

```
<form role='form' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

When I used this it was to submit multiple text fields, and a single image file, via the HTML form. Then in my `parseForm` function I would bundle these into a single object to be saved to mongo as follows

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      var temp = fields;
      temp.image = {};
      temp.image.data = fs.readFileSync(files.image[0].path);
      temp.image.contentType = 'image';
      var product = new Product(temp);
      product.save();
      res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: how to access to the stream inside form.parse?