# How to send a file to Nodejs using FormData and have Node send back a confirmation message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Hi I'm working on this simple form trying to send a file to my Nodejs server using `FormData`, but for some reason Node never receives it. Also How can I have Node send back a confirmation message on the page saying that file was received. What is it that I'm doing wrong or missing?. Please help. Thank you in advance. Here's my code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var fd = new FormData();   
 fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
  url: '/uploadfile',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
  alert(data);
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <form enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type= "text" name = "theName"/>
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
   <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Server (Nodejs)**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();

 /* GET users listing. */

 router.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendfile('./public/html/form-file.html');
 });

 /* POST file */
 router.post('/', function(req , res){

 console.log('Request received: ');
 console.log(req.body) // this line helps inspect the request so you can see    whether the data is in the url (GET) or the req body (POST)
 console.log('\nRequest recieved: \nmethod: ' + req.method + '\nurl: ' +  req.url) // this line logs just the method and url

 res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');

 });

 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149545/uploading-images-using-node-js-express-and-mongoose

Comment: It is not a duplicated question because I'm using Ajax and Jquery for  backend validation purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HERE'S THE BEST SOLUTION to this question** -> Credit  goes to: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/ajax-file-upload-node-js/

**HTML**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>File upload Node.</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/api/photo"
      method="post">
  <input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  <span id = "status"></span>
 </form>
 </body>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
     $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");

    $(this).ajaxSubmit({

        error: function(xhr) {
                status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
        },

        success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
                $("#status").empty().text(response);
        }
   });

  return false;
  });    
});
</script>
</html>
```

**SERVER**

```
var express         =       require("express");
var multer          =       require('multer');
var app             =       express();
var upload          =       multer({ dest: './uploads/'});

app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename+Date.now();
},
onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
},
onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
 }
}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    res.end("File is uploaded");
  });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
 console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using formidables,

```
var formidable = require("formidable");

function imageUpload(req,res){

 var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

 form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {


 console.log("imagePath:"+files.filepath.path);
 //assume <input type = "file" name="filepath">
 res.send("file uploaded");
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post initially didn't have a response being sent in your example

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./public/html/form-file.html');
});

/* POST file */
router.post('/', function(req , res){

    console.log('Request received: ');
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({message: 'file was received'});

 });

 module.exports = router;
```

Then in your success callback

```
...
success: function(response) {
    alert(response.message);
}
...
```

Comment: you know that JSON cannot have a property that holds a file value right?

Comment: how would the html file look like?