# Upload image from JQuery to Node JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I need to upload an image file from my `HTML` page. However, I am not going to use the `form` tag since there are other `form` fields (textfields, checkbox etc) that will be used to pass data to the server later.

My back end is in `Node JS`. All what I want is to retrieve the image data (file) from the `Node Js` end. How can I do this

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
            <h2>File Uploader</h2>
            <h4>coligo.io</h4>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg upload-btn" type="button">Upload File</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <input id="upload-input" type="file" name="uploads" multiple="multiple"></br>
```

JQuery

```
$('.upload-btn').on('click', function (){
    $('#upload-input').click();
    $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
    $('.progress-bar').width('0%');
});

$('#upload-input').on('change', function(){

  var files = $(this).get(0).files;

  if (files.length > 0){
    // create a FormData object which will be sent as the data payload in the
    // AJAX request
    var formData = new FormData();
       // loop through all the selected files and add them to the formData object
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      // add the files to formData object for the data payload
      formData.append('uploads', tmppath);

    }
    $.ajax({
      url: '/myp/imgup',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data){
          console.log('upload successful!\n' + data);
      },
      xhr: function() {
        // create an XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // listen to the 'progress' event
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {

          if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            // calculate the percentage of upload completed
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);

            // update the Bootstrap progress bar with the new percentage
            $('.progress-bar').text(percentComplete + '%');
            $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');

            // once the upload reaches 100%, set the progress bar text to done
            if (percentComplete === 100) {
              $('.progress-bar').html('Done');
            }

          }

        }, false);

        return xhr;
      }
    });

  }
});
```

NODE JS

```
router.post('/imgup', function(req, res){
    console.log(' File name '+req.files.upload);

});
```

I have been trying this out for several days, with no luck. Can someone help me out.

Comment: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Comment: I tired this before, but it was no use. May be I applied it in the wrong way in my code. Can you show me how it is done ?

Comment: What about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34442688/747579 ?

Comment: Tried it as well. It uses `multer `

Comment: hope to get answer . Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using the `multer` module:

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();
app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});


var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

app.post('/api/file',function(req,res){
    var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userFile');
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

An example with the `formidable` module:

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
http = require('http'),
util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      if (err)
          do-smth; // process error

      // Copy file from temporary place
      // var fs = require('fs');
      // fs.rename(file.path, <targetPath>, function (err) { ... });         

      // Send result on client
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8080);
```

Excerpted from [Node.js -
 File upload](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816202112/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/4080/file-upload). The original authors were [Iceman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6237235/iceman), [Aikon Mogwai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6121703/aikon-mogwai) and [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5526354/mikhail). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/4080).  The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 4080.

Comment: How to do it for a remote file upload eg: on AWS S3 ?

Comment: Not used s3, but having used other cloud providers, im assuming u have an sdk to help. either way you'll need to put the upload to the storage facility after the file is on your server.